# Error: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present. Even though I have added it

Tags: php, apache, unity-game-engine, server

I am building an application in Unity and exporting to HTML5. When I try to make a simple GET request I am getting this error:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://example.co.uk/request.php?foo=bar'
>   from origin 'http://anothersite.co.uk' has been blocked by CORS
>   policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the
>   requested resource.

I have seen many questions asking this on forums, and people give these sort of responses (as I've interpreted them):

> 1. The server / site you are requesting from should set the Headers, to either accept the specific domain you are requesting from or just set it as a wild card
> 2. Disable web security in your browser
> 3. Use a proxy, such as https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com

The first one makes sense to me, but I have tried the following on the server side to no avail:

1. Set the headers in the .htaccess file. Such as Header Set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
2. Set the headers in the "request" php file: header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://anothersite.co.uk'); (I also tried "*")
3. I tried sending the headers in the request FROM "anothersite.co.uk" in the Unity code.
4. I tried what people suggested with https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com by passing it the URL but this didn't work atall, maybe I missunderstood it. I really don't like this as a solution anyway.. makes the whole thing seem pointless.

Any tips would really help, I'm so sorry if I have just missunderstood the whole thing, but I can't make head or tail.. I just keep getting the same error shown above.

Thanks in advance for any help! :)

Comment: So to be clear the server you are trying to get data from, you added the cors header on that .htaccess right? did you tell apache to reread the config?

Comment: Yes thats right. Sorry im not sure what you mean by "reread"? Does it have to read it twice?

Comment: If you edit the apache config it often doesnt read the new changes until its restarted or told to read the new config...

Comment: I have tried restarting server, and have also disabled this feature in cpanel: "Use a Global DCV Passthrough instead of .htaccess modification (requires EA4)".. so it's still ignoring my .htaccess :(

Comment: then id suggest you go find some apache forums and see if they can help you as to why its not reading your config

Answer (score 0):

I use a version of the following PHP code for serving data and it seems to work.

```
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'])) {
    // Decide if the origin in $_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'] is one
    // you want to allow, and if so:
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: {$_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']}");
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
    header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 86400');    // cache for 1 day
}

// Access-Control headers are received during OPTIONS requests
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'OPTIONS') {

    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_METHOD']))
        // may also be using PUT, PATCH, HEAD etc
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS");         

    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']))
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: {$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']}");

    exit(0);
}
```

Comment: I tried this (on the server I sending requests to), but still not working. I also have tried restarting the entire webserver (seems excessive). Is the server possibly overriding my htacess and php file header settings?